# Is there a difference between $\ce{}$ and \ce{}?

Tags: chemistry, mhchem

So with the `mhchem` package, I am able to write chemical equations conviniently. However, I am confused on whether `\ce{}` with dollar signs or without them are equivalent. The guides I've read told me to add `$$` on the outside but I don't see any difference. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Page 4 of the `mhchem` documentation states:

> This works in text mode (even in headings) and in math mode.

---

There's however a small difference in the visual output:
In text mode, `\ce{}` uses the text font, while the math-mode `$\ce{}$` uses the math font. Depending on your setup, both fonts might be indistinguishable, or quite different (e.g., in headings where often a bold text font is used).

---

General advice: when in doubt, the manual of the package as posted on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/mhchem?lang=en) is always a good first place to check.